# Is it possible to scale the size and color of nodes/vertices using ggnetwork based on two variables?

Tags: ggnetwork

Working from the 'blood type' example in the documentation (Tyner, Briatte and Hoffman):

```
> bt <- as.character( unique( blood$edges$from ) )
> bt_df <- data.frame( type=bt, spin=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),charm=c(8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
Browse[1]> bt_df
  type spin charm
1  AB-    1     8
2  AB+    2     7
3   A-    3     6
4   A+    4     5
5   B-    5     4
6   B+    6     3
7   O-    7     2
8   O+    8     1
```

Is it possible to plot the network graph varying the color of vertices across some palette based on the value of "spin" and varying vertex size based on the value of "charm"?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the documentation along with some trial-and-error. The key step is "geom_nodes(size=bt_df$spin, color=bt_df$charm)".

```
ggplot( ggnetwork(grph, layout="circle", arrow.gap=0.05),aes(x,y,xend=xend,yend=yend)) +
          geom_edges(color="grey50", arrow=arrow(length=unit(10,"pt"), type="closed")) +
          scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
          geom_nodes(size=bt_df$spin, color=bt_df$charm) +
          geom_nodetext(aes(label=vertex.names), color="grey80") + 
          theme_blank() +
          coord_fixed( 0.5 )
```